# uninstall ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, bootloader

I am trying to uninstall ubuntu to install windows. when I tried to boot it is taking me to grub prompt. is there any other ways to boot without using grub or if using grub is compulsory then what is the process?

Answer (score 1):

Please [make a back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) of your data first!

You don't need to uninstall Ubuntu to install Windows: Just boot the Windows Installation CD and re-format the hard drive in the Windows set-up screen.

Sorry to see you go!  :-(

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall Grub Bootloader by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KV84OabGB08

But I suggest you Ubuntu operating system instead of Microsoft Windows. Because Ubuntu means "compassion and humanity". It is a free and open source operating system. Better than Windows in every aspect.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...